# Customize LWC combobox label with different colors

Tags: lightning-web-components

All,

Is there a way we can achieve this in LWC combobox

[image]

I tried to insert HTML tag like `<font color="Yellow">` for label but it fully rendering the HTML without parsing the HTML tag. I need to do in  `<lightning-combobox>` . can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't in the default implementation, but you can take the component code, which is open source, (https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/combobox) and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank You. Will try that.